# How can I call a Node.js function from a client-side event listener function?

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, client-side, event-listener

Good afternoon!

I came across an interesting challenge (for a javascript newcomer like me).

Scenario:

I have a HTML select element with 3 option elements (experiment 1, experiment 2, experiment 3). If I click on experiment 1 I would like to call the getPatientDataFromExperiment() function from Node.js file dataHandler.js within my addEventListener function of the select element. The event listener works fine. But I don't get access to the function. During my research I came across topics which could potentially solve my problem, but to be honest - I didn't quite understand them (especially the socket solution). I am using Node.js (v8.9.4) and Visual Studio Code.

What have I done so far:

I tried stupidly to load the script which contains the function via a XmlHttpRequest. But in the corresponding response I've just got my script back as a string.

Question:

Is there a more or less simple solution to call a server-side function of a Node.js file from a client-side event listener function (especially without refreshing the site)?

I would be very grateful for your precious help and a demo example. Thank you very much!

Research:

[node.js executing server side function from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912489/node-js-executing-server-side-function-from-client-side)

[How to call a server side function from client side (e.g. html button onclick) in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831783/how-to-call-a-server-side-function-from-client-side-e-g-html-button-onclick-i)

Code (Client-side, eventHandler.js):

```
document.getElementById("experiment").addEventListener("change", function()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("target3").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
    }

    request.open("GET","javascript/dataHandler.js",true);
    request.send();
});
```

Code (Node, dataHandler.js):

```
function getPatientDataFromExperiment()
{
    alert("Function call worked");
}
```

Result: getPatientDataFromExperiment function all as plain text

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to host the dataHandler.js
2) Don't use alert in a NodeJS project
If I were you I would use ExpressJS.
Create a new folder in somewhere but not inside your frontend project.
Then run

```
npm init
npm install --save-dev express
```

Then create a file there called `server.js` with this content:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Function call worked'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Then you can host it in your localhost with the following command:

```
node server.js
```

Then you need to modify this line in your frontend code

```
request.open("GET","javascript/dataHandler.js",true);
```

to this:

```
request.open("GET","http://localhost:3000",true);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. But I don't get it. Isn't it just the equivalent of http.createServer from Node.js? How can I host my dataHandler.js? I deleted alert (thank you for your hint).

Comment: Not really. http.createServer creates a server but to set up complex things (like routing) is more a little bit complicated. ExpressJS simplifies it.

Comment: I will have a look at the API reference of Express because at the moment I am quite confused and still don't get it and I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: I recommend some youtube tutorial about express before you start, because these gives you an initial idea about the framework. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6_CoHNSbwc

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendation!

Comment: @Csaba I have similar question. I am trying to save data to database. and after that i want to return back to same route but with some textboxes disabled. i don't know how to handle DOM from server-side js

Comment: You have two choices:
- The old-school way: Render html from Node.js (not recommended). 
- The modern API-way: Return a JSON to the frontend and handle the json with a frontend framework (Angular, React, Vue.js)